# Oracle Text use Base_Letter setting when creating index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, diacritics, oracle-text

On my database there is a product title. We need to be able to search this so that it isn't accent sensitive, ie searching 'Dorthey' will still return 'Dórthéy'.

We are already creating an Oracle Text index. The setting for converting accented characters to base letters is called base_letter, and needs to be turned on.

This is how the index is created.

```
create index ITITLE_PSIPRODUCTTITLE on PSI.PSIPRODUCTTITLE(PT_TITLE) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context
```

Do I turn on this setting when creating the index, and how? Or is the base_letter setting turned on elsewhere?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a `BASIC_LEXER` where you set the `BASE_LETTER` to `true`.

You use the `BASIC_LEXER` in the creation of the text index as demonstrated in the example

```
begin
ctx_ddl.create_preference (
'my_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER' );
ctx_ddl.set_attribute( 'my_lexer',
'BASE_LETTER', 'true' );
end;
/

create table tab as
select 1 id, 'schön' txt from dual union all
select 2 id, 'schoen' txt from dual union all
select 3 id, 'schon' txt from dual union all
select 4 id, 'schnix' txt from dual;

create index tab_ttx on tab(txt) indextype is ctxsys.context
parameters ( 'lexer my_lexer' );


select * from tab where contains(txt,'schon')>0;

        ID TXT   
---------- ------
         1 schön 
         3 schon
```

Please check the other parameters such as `ALTERNATE_SPELLING` and/or `OVERRIDE_BASE_LETTER`  as illustrated in this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/oracle-text-and-accented-characters)

Alternatively consult the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ccref/oracle-text-alternative-spelling.html#GUID-17B0101A-CF8C-44E2-8419-71969D571A81)